# Calculation of values that rely on a date variable

Tags: sql, sorting, date, sas

I am trying to calculate the value of the last measurement taken (according to the date column) divided by the lowest value recorded (according to the measurement column)  if two values in the “SUBJECT” column match and two values in the “PROCEDURE” column match. The the calculation would be produced in a new column. I am having trouble with this and I would appreciate a solution to this matter.

```
data Have;
    input Subject Type :$12. Date &:anydtdte. Procedure :$12. Measurement;
    format date yymmdd10.;
    datalines;

500   Initial    15 AUG 2017     Invasive     20 
500   Initial    15 AUG 2017     Surface      35 
500   Followup   15 AUG 2018     Invasive     54 
428   Followup    15 AUG 2018    Outer        29 
765   Seventh     3 AUG 2018     Other        13 
500   Followup    3 JUL 2018     Surface      98 
428   Initial     3 JUL 2017     Outer        10 
765   Initial     20 JUL 2019    Other        19 
610   Third       20 AUG 2019    Invasive     66 
610   Initial     17 Mar 2018    Invasive     17 
;

*Intended output table
Subject Type      Date           Procedure    Measurement     Output
500   Initial    15 AUG 2017     Invasive        20            20/20
500   Initial    15 AUG 2017     Surface         35            35/35
500   Followup   15 AUG 2018     Invasive        54            54/20
428   Followup    15 AUG 2018    Outer           29            29/10
765   Seventh     3 AUG 2018     Other           13            13/19
500   Followup    3 JUL 2018     surface         98            98/35
428   Initial     3 JUL 2017     Outer           10            10/10
765   Initial     20 JUL 2019    Other           19            19/19
610   Third       20 AUG 2019    Invasive        66            66/17
610   Initial     17 Mar 2018    Invasive        17            17/17 ;

*Attempt;
PROC SQL;
    create table want as
    select a.*,
        (select measurement as measurement_last_date
         from have
         where subject = a.subject and type = a.type 
         having date = max(date)) / min(a.measurement) as ratio
    from have as a
    group by subject, type
    order by subject, type, date;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need use statement **retain** with **data step**.

the statement will retain your last row and you can 'll compare the last row with actual row processed.

link of some tutorial of how use statement retain.
[enter link description here](https://www.sascrunch.com/retain-statement.html)

SAS documentation 
[enter link description here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p0t2ac0tfzcgbjn112mu96hkgg9o.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)